# How can I allow a user to download a set of files to a specific directory automatically?

Tags: java, flash

I have an internal app that creates a set of files, they are then zipped up with php and presented to the user with download headers.  The user then downloads the zip file, must unzip the folder and copy the files over to a specific directory on their computer.

I need some direction on how I can allow the user to preset this folder so when they click a download button, all of the files in the set will just download to that specific folder on their hard drive.

I realize that besides having the user set their browser's download directory, this isn't normally possible.  But I know that it can be done with a java applet or maybe flash.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to create a small app like this.  I would assume the user would have to download the app and allow it access the first time they used the site, then after that, I would like them to be able to just click a button and download the files.

I am quite certain that this can be done, as I have seen it before.  But I can no longer find the site that did it.  Even if the app at least popped up a file browser window to select the folder to download to that had the preferred folder pre-selected, that would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

-On your server create a file with a list of files to be downloaded as a relative path to it.

-Retrieve this list as an array/list of strings

-Create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and submit a `Runnable` for each of the files (strings) in the list. The Runnable should work on `SERVER_URL + RELATIVE_LINK`

That should get you started...

Oh, btw, your applet needs to be signed in order to access the disk drive.

If it is an option, create a runnable jar and let the user download it.